# How to hide a tab from a tabpanel when it gives the output through a php foreach

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, joomla

I am using Joomla latest version integrated with a particular component. There I can add custom tab fields. So the inserted custom fields shows like as below mentioned while standard custom fields are named such as "tab-1", "tab-2".

```
<?php foreach($tabsGroup AS $t):  ?>

<li rel="<?=$t->getElementValue('alias')?>">
<a class="jd-tab-text"><?=$t->getElementValue('name')?></a>
</li>

<?php endforeach; ?>
```

I have inserted 4 custom fields and i need to hide only one tab according to user packages. Please advice on this.

Thank You

Comment: `according to user packages`?? What sort of package? Usergroups based on subscriptions?

Comment: I have created 4 user packages according to the user payment methods. such as Platinum, Gold, Silver and Basic. my custom tabs are products, brands, branches, videos. I need to hide videos tab if the user has the Silver package. these tabs has ids (14, 15, 16, 17).

Comment: I used the below code. But it hides the first tab. I want to hide 4th tab                                                           <script type="text/javascript">
                    function hide() {
                        document.getElementById("video_hide").style.display = "none";
                    }
                </script>

Comment: You first need to detect the userpackage of the currently logged in user. Which extention are you ising to create these packages?

Comment: Hi, I managed to do it. There was a section down "<?php foreach($tabsGroup AS $t):  ?>
     <div id="<?=$t->getElementValue('alias')?>">
             <?=$t->show()?>
     </div>".                                                                Here using the database i found the ids and using jQuery i hide the particular tab. I am using a component which related to joomla.   Thank you very much all for the support.